How can I merge the identical legends that have different size scales on a plot_layout (patchwork)?
I am attempting to place multiple graphs into one page using patchwork. I have the separate graphs as Group 1 and Group 2 with their 2 legends in each case.


However, when I use patchwork to put them together, the legends do not collect (See below).

data(mtcars)
mydata1<-mtcars %>% slice(1:16)
mydata2<-mtcars %>% slice(17:32)

library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
P1<-ggplot()+
    geom_point(data = mydata1, mapping = aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, 
    col = disp, size = hp))+
    ggtitle('Group 1')
P2<-ggplot()+
    geom_point(data = mydata2, mapping = aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, 
    col = disp, size = hp))+
    ggtitle('Group 2')
P3 <- P1 + P2 +
plot_layout(guides='collect', ncol = 2)
P3

I was expecting the legends to be merged such that the legend for disp will cover its spread of data and the legend for hp will apply to both group 1 and group 2 since they have different ranges, to give something like this:

Note you don't have any functions that generate random values so you don't need to set a seed for reproducibility.

For the guides to be collected, they need to be identical (same limits, breaks etc.), so in this case you need to make sure the color and size limits cover the full range of the data across groups.
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

P1<-ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = mydata1, mapping = aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, 
                                           col = disp, size = hp))+
  scale_color_continuous(limits = range(mtcars$disp)) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = range(mtcars$hp)) +
  ggtitle('Group 1')

P2<-ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = mydata2, mapping = aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, 
                                           col = disp, size = hp))+
  scale_color_continuous(limits = range(mtcars$disp)) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = range(mtcars$hp)) +
  ggtitle('Group 2')

P1 + P2 +
  plot_layout(guides='collect', ncol = 2)


